# What's the regex in this package installation?

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management, regular-expression

I wanted to install `libatk-bridge2.0`, so I ran `sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0
[sudo] password for christoph: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libatk-bridge2.0-0' for regex 'libatk-bridge2.0'
Note, selecting 'libatk-bridge2.0-dev' for regex 'libatk-bridge2.0'
libatk-bridge2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.18.1-2ubuntu1).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libxtst-dev x11proto-record-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libxtst-dev
  x11proto-record-dev
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 274 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,804 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libdbus-1-dev amd64 1.10.6-1ubuntu3 [161 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 x11proto-record-dev all 1.14.2-1 [33.6 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libxtst-dev amd64 2:1.2.2-1 [17.0 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libatspi2.0-dev amd64 2.18.3-4ubuntu1 [59.2 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libatk-bridge2.0-dev amd64 2.18.1-2ubuntu1 [2,824 B]
Fetched 274 kB in 0s (340 kB/s)               
Selecting previously unselected package libdbus-1-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 336246 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdbus-1-dev_1.10.6-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbus-1-dev:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-record-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../x11proto-record-dev_1.14.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11proto-record-dev (1.14.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxtst-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxtst-dev_2%3a1.2.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxtst-dev:amd64 (2:1.2.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatspi2.0-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libatspi2.0-dev_2.18.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatspi2.0-dev (2.18.3-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libatk-bridge2.0-dev_2.18.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 (2.18.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libdbus-1-dev:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up x11proto-record-dev (1.14.2-1) ...
Setting up libxtst-dev:amd64 (2:1.2.2-1) ...
Setting up libatspi2.0-dev (2.18.3-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 (2.18.1-2ubuntu1) ...
```

I really only noticed something was wrong when I figured out I don't need `libatk-bridge2` a few minutes later, so I wanted to purge it.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libatk-bridge2.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libatk-bridge2.0-0' for regex 'libatk-bridge2.0'
Note, selecting 'libatk-bridge2.0-dev' for regex 'libatk-bridge2.0'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas adium-theme-ubuntu appstream apt-xapian-index
  apturl-common dbus-property-service dleyna-server fonts-droid-fallback
  fonts-noto-mono gdebi-core gedit-common gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
  gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gksu gnome-control-center-data
  gnome-software-common gnome-video-effects gtk2-engines-murrine
  guile-2.0-libs iio-sensor-proxy indicator-network intel-gpu-tools
  latexila-data liba11y-profile-manager-0.1-0 libandroid-properties1
  libappindicator1 libappstream3 libatspi2.0-dev libboost-log1.58.0
  libboost-regex1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0 libconnectivity-qt1
  libcontent-hub0 libdbus-1-dev libdbus-cpp5 libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1
  libdleyna-core-1.0-3 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libept1.5.0 libevent-2.0-5
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libgexiv2-2 libgflags2v5 libgksu2-0
  libgoogle-glog0v5 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgssdp-1.0-3 libgupnp-1.0-4
  libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libhardware2 libhybris
  libhybris-common1 libhybris-utils libindicator7 liblibertine1
  liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 libmedia1 libminiupnpc10 libnatpmp1
  libonline-accounts-client1 libonline-accounts-daemon1 libonline-accounts-qt1
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libprocess-cpp3
  libqmenumodel0 libqofono-qt5-0 libqqwing2v5 libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libsgutils2-2
  libssh-4 libsystemsettings1 libtrust-store2 libubuntu-app-launch2
  libubuntu-download-manager-client1 libubuntu-download-manager-common1
  libudm-common1 libunwind8 liburcu4 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libxapian-1.3-5
  libxtst-dev network-manager-openvpn ofono oneconf-common oxideqt-codecs
  python-aptdaemon python-attr python-cups python-dbus python-debian
  python-debtagshw python-defer python-dirspec python-gpgme python-oneconf
  python-pam python-piston-mini-client python-pyasn1-modules python-serial
  python-service-identity python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core
  python-twisted-web python-xapian python-zope.interface python3-brlapi
  python3-gi-cairo python3-gnupg python3-louis python3-mako python3-oneconf
  python3-piston-mini-client python3-speechd python3-xapian1.3 qmenumodel-qml
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings
  qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtsysteminfo
  qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts2 qml-module-ubuntu-web
  qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0
  qtdeclarative5-ofono0.2 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
  realmd remmina-common rhythmbox-data shotwell-common
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins sqlite3 syslinux syslinux-common
  syslinux-legacy system-image-common system-image-dbus texlive
  transmission-common ubuntu-keyboard-data ubuntu-wallpapers
  ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial ubuntuone-client-data ubuntuone-credentials-common
  unity-webapps-qml urfkill usb-creator-common webapp-container webbrowser-app
  whoopsie-preferences x11proto-record-dev xbrlapi
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu click click-apparmor
  gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 libclick-0.4-0 pinentry-curses
  python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click python3-click-package
  python3-libapparmor
Suggested packages:
  click-reviewers-tools ubuntu-app-launch-tools | upstart-app-launch-tools
  pinentry-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  a11y-profile-manager-indicator* account-plugin-facebook*
  account-plugin-flickr* account-plugin-google* activity-log-manager*
  adwaita-icon-theme* aisleriot* apport-gtk* apturl* bamfdaemon* baobab*
  cheese* compiz* compiz-gnome* dconf-editor* deja-dup* eog* evince*
  evolution* evolution-data-server* evolution-plugins* file-roller* firefox*
  gcr* gdebi* gedit* ghex* gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1* gir1.2-gtk-3.0*
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0* gir1.2-keybinder-3.0* gir1.2-peas-1.0* gir1.2-rb-3.0*
  gir1.2-totem-1.0* gir1.2-vte-2.91* gir1.2-webkit2-4.0* gir1.2-wnck-3.0*
  gkbd-capplet* gnome-bluetooth* gnome-calculator* gnome-calendar*
  gnome-disk-utility* gnome-font-viewer* gnome-icon-theme* gnome-keyring*
  gnome-mahjongg* gnome-mines* gnome-orca* gnome-power-manager*
  gnome-screensaver* gnome-screenshot* gnome-search-tool* gnome-session-bin*
  gnome-session-canberra* gnome-software* gnome-sudoku* gnome-system-log*
  gnome-system-monitor* gnome-terminal* gnome-user-guide* gnome-user-share*
  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0* gucharmap* gvfs-backends* humanity-icon-theme*
  ibus* ibus-gtk3* ibus-table* indicator-application* indicator-appmenu*
  indicator-bluetooth* indicator-keyboard* indicator-printers* kazam*
  language-selector-gnome* latexila* libaccount-plugin-1.0-0*
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth* libaccount-plugin-google*
  libappindicator3-1* libatk-adaptor* libatk-bridge2.0-0*
  libatk-bridge2.0-dev* libavahi-ui-gtk3-0* libcanberra-gtk3-0*
  libcanberra-gtk3-module* libchamplain-0.12-0* libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0*
  libcheese-gtk25* libcheese8* libclutter-1.0-0* libclutter-gst-3.0-0*
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0* libcryptui0a* libedataserverui-1.2-1*
  libevdocument3-4* libevolution* libevview3-3* libgail-3-0* libgcr-ui-3-1*
  libgnome-bluetooth13* libgnome-desktop-3-12* libgnomekbd8* libgtk-3-0*
  libgtk-3-bin* libgtk-3-common* libgtkhex-3-0* libgtkmm-3.0-1v5*
  libgtksourceview-3.0-1* libgtkspell3-3-0* libgucharmap-2-90-7*
  libgweather-3-6* libido3-0.1-0* libindicator3-7* libkeybinder-3.0-0*
  libmetacity-private3a* libnautilus-extension1a* libnm-gtk0* libnma0*
  libpeas-1.0-0* libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader*
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer* librhythmbox-core9* libtimezonemap1*
  libtotem0* libunity-control-center1* libunity-core-6.0-9*
  libunity-gtk3-parser0* libunity-misc4* libunity-settings-daemon1*
  libunity-webapps0* libvte-2.91-0* libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37*
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2* libwebkitgtk-3.0-0* libwnck-3-0* libyelp0*
  light-themes* meld* mousetweaks* nautilus* nautilus-dropbox*
  nautilus-megasync* nautilus-sendto* nautilus-share* network-manager-gnome*
  network-manager-pptp-gnome* notify-osd* onboard* onboard-data* oneconf*
  pinentry-gnome3* policykit-1-gnome* python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets*
  python-ubuntu-sso-client* python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets* python3-pyatspi*
  remmina* remmina-plugin-rdp* remmina-plugin-vnc* rhythmbox*
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist* rhythmbox-plugins* seahorse* seahorse-daemon*
  session-shortcuts* sessioninstaller* shotwell* simple-scan* software-center*
  software-properties-gtk* system-config-printer-gnome* totem* totem-plugins*
  transmission-gtk* ubuntu-artwork* ubuntu-desktop* ubuntu-docs* ubuntu-mono*
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk* ubuntu-session* ubuntu-software*
  ubuntu-sso-client* unity* unity-asset-pool* unity-control-center*
  unity-control-center-signon* unity-greeter* unity-gtk3-module*
  unity-scope-calculator* unity-scope-gdrive* unity-scope-manpages*
  unity-services* unity-settings-daemon* unity-tweak-tool*
  unity-webapps-common* unity-webapps-service* update-manager*
  update-notifier* usb-creator-gtk* vino* xdg-user-dirs-gtk* xdiagnose* yelp*
  zeitgeist-datahub* zenity*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu click click-apparmor
  gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 libclick-0.4-0 pinentry-curses
  python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click python3-click-package
  python3-libapparmor
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 206 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 350 kB of archives.
After this operation, 592 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

As you can see, it intends to delete a lot of stuff. Both the install command and the purge command say something about a regex. But how is `libatk-bridge2.0` a regex? Of course `foo` is a regex that only matches `foo` but if `libatk-bridge2.0` only had the one matching string `libatk-bridge2.0`, apt-get shouldn't select for example `libatk-bridge2.0-0` for it.

Of course it's very easy to purge the exact packages which have been installed by that if you still have the output ...

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libxtst-dev   x11proto-record-dev
[sudo] password for christoph: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libatk-bridge2.0-dev* libatspi2.0-dev* libdbus-1-dev* libxtst-dev*
  x11proto-record-dev*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,804 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 336354 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 (2.18.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libatspi2.0-dev (2.18.3-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libdbus-1-dev:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3) ...
Removing libxtst-dev:amd64 (2:1.2.2-1) ...
Removing x11proto-record-dev (1.14.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

... but why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The actual package name is [`libatk-bridge2.0-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libatk-bridge2.0-0) therefore `libatk-bridge2.0` matches: `libatk-bridge2.0-0` (which is pretty much always there) and `libatk-bridge2.0-dev`.

---

You did not install `libatk-bridge2.0` you did install other things:

```
Note, selecting 'libatk-bridge2.0-0' for regex 'libatk-bridge2.0'
Note, selecting 'libatk-bridge2.0-dev' for regex 'libatk-bridge2.0'
libatk-bridge2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.18.1-2ubuntu1).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libxtst-dev x11proto-record-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libxtst-dev
  x11proto-record-dev
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And `libatk-bridge2.0` did match them because the actual package name is [`libatk-bridge2.0-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libatk-bridge2.0-0).

Then, your `purge` used `libatk-bridge2.0` again and did match `libatk-bridge2.0-0` to be removed.  Provoking:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ***A LOT OF STUFF**
```

This removes a lot of stuff because ATK (and its DBUS bridge) is close to the bottom of the GNOME dependency tree.  Therefore pretty much everything that depended on the GNOME environment and GTK was marked for purge.

---

`apt-get` does perform regex matches when it cannot find an exact package name.  From `man apt-get` (`install` command section):

```
 If no package matches the given expression and the expression
 contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX
 regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the
 database. Any matches are then installed (or removed). Note that
 matching is done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and
 'lowest'. If this is undesired, anchor the regular expression with
 a '^' or '$' character, or create a more specific regular
 expression.
```

So yeah, `libatk-bridge2.0` has a dot (`.`) therefore it is good enough as a regex in `apt-get`'s eyes.

Comment: But why does it match those 2 packages?

Comment: @UTF-8 Ah OK, that is a little confusing on apt-get's part, I admit.  I made an edit about the regex processing.

Comment: Thanks! Seems not to be contradicted be the behavior of `sudo apt-get install a.`. I don't get why one would implement it like that, though. I mean, seeing it as a regex is one thing and choosing a substring might also be sensible. But only requiring that the package name to be a superstring of any string which matches the regex seems a little off. If I were to type something like `abc.`, I'd expect that to match `abca`, `abcd`, `abcf`, etc. but not `abcde` and certainly not `zabcde`.

Comment: @UTF-8, Heh, that's an `apt` peculiarity (and they do not do `^<regex>$` by default, they expect you to add that).  `yum install` uses globs instead of regexes, and `pacman -S` does not do any kind of matching.  Everyone have its quirks.  I guess (only guess) that apt did it this way to make it consistent with `apt-cache search`, which uses POSIX regexes by default.

Answer (score 0):

regex wildcards will be true when what you search is contained in what you are searching for.  since the two packeges it is trying to uninstall have the word you inputted in thier names, it returns true.  you could try adding in regex delimiters for begin and end string, but all that aside, does apt-get remove work? you could have deleted a config file that had dependencies in it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be coherent with the behavior of `sudo apt-get install a` which prints out `E: Unable to locate package a` and doesn't propose other packages even though I'm fairly sure there are quite a few packages containing the string "a".

Comment: this is from the man pages " Each package is a package name, not a
           fully qualified filename (for instance, in a Debian system,
           apt-utils would be the argument provided, not
           apt-utils_1.2.10_amd64.deb)"

Comment: Isn't `libatk-bridge2.0-dev` a package name? (Therefore `libatk-bridge2.0` shouldn't be the name of that same package.) Can a package list several names under which it wants to be found?

Comment: it all depends on how the developer added their package to the repo, some repo managers have standards, apt-get is pretty lax.  i dont know why the dev shows up. but it is possible it is a dependency of the full package

Comment: @grochmal explained why that is in his answer. It's because of how `apt-get` uses its inputs, not because of the packages.